# MySQL command not running from Bash file

Tags: mysql, bash

I have the following command

```
  mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e "select * from table limit 10;"
```

which when I run it from a linux server it works normally (10 tuples are displayed)

When the following is added in a bash file

```
  echo 'mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e select * from table limit 10;' >> /root/test.log
```

nothing happens. In the log file, only the echo string is being displayed.
Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: You (?) have written a code that outputs a string to a file. That's correct. And probably you better start with explanation what you want to achieve

Comment: just to play it safe: have you noticed that the database and passwords are different on the two commands you posted, haven't you? And you have just shared your pass with us.

Comment: @zerkms - I want to write the command result in the log instead of the string

Comment: Then don't echo the string into the log file. Echo just outputs its arguments - it doesn't execute anything. Try typing "echo remove all my files" - you'll get "remove all my files" on your screen. Echo just echoes - it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is because you just `echo` your command as a string and redirect the output of echo to the log file. You do nothing else ;-)

Just run the command as you would do on the command line and redirect the output of `mysql` command (instead of `echo`) to your logfile:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e "select * from table limit 10;" >> /root/test.log
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because

```
mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e "select * from table limit 10;"
```

Is not the same as

```
mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e select * from table limit 10;
```

Try using this:

```
echo 'mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e "select * from table limit 10;"' >> /root/test.log
```

And then actually invoke the command

```
mysql -u root -ppass myDB -e "select * from table limit 10;" >> /root/test.log
```